# Updating URL query string with JS / Rails and a dropdown form

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I am looking to update a url when a selection is made from a dropdown. I would like to have the query to be dynamic, here is the following code:

```
  <select id="mySchool" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <% @schools.each do |school| %>
      <option value="<%= school.id %>"><%= school.name %></option>
    <% end %>
  </select>

  <%= link_to "Apply School", "schools/assign_users?user_id=#{@user.id}&school_id=", :class => "btn btn-primary", :type => "button" %>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the best way to create select in rails. You should rather use [`rails select_tag helper`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag) like this:

```
<%= select_tag 'school_id', options_for_select(@schools.collect{ |s| [u.name, u.id] }), id: "mySchool" %>
```

> I am looking to update a url when a selection is made from a dropdown.

I think instead of showing the link upfront you should show the link only when a user select a value from dropdown so your code should be something like this:

```
<%= select_tag 'school_id', options_for_select(@schools.collect{ |s| [u.name, u.id] }), id: "mySchool" %>

<div id="schoolLink"></div>

#_link.html.erb
<%= link_to "Apply School", "schools/assign_users?user_id=#{user.id}&school_id=#{school.id}", :class => "btn btn-primary", :type => "button" %>
```

Now make a route to which you want to send the ajax request to:

```
post 'selected_school/:id' => 'school#selected', as: "select_school"
```

write a js function which will send ajax request on changing values in dropdown

```
$(document).on("change","#mySchool",function(e){
  var school_id = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/selected_school",
    data: {id : school_id }
  });
});
```

Find school and user inside controller and then finally render link by js

```
#school_controller.rb
def selected
  @school = School.find(params[:id]) # find school by the passed id
  @user = current_user # your logic to find user
end

#app/views/school/selected.js
$("#schoolLink").html("<%=j render partial: 'link', locals: {user: @user, school: @school} %>");
```

For details checkout [**`Working with Javascript in Rails`**](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#a-simple-example)